# Using seed to send bitcoin from a wallet's specific private key

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, seed, mnemonic-seed, bip

I'm new to bitcoin and I've recently been reading on the concept of **wallet**. If I understand correctly, a wallet is a collection of one or more pairs **address + private key** (an address is where BTC can be sent to, and a private key is used to spend BTC from its associated address). I'm not sure if there is something between the private key and the address known as **public key**.

If I understand correctly, the difference between **nondeterministic wallets** and **deterministic wallets** is that with non-HD wallets each pair "address + private key" is generated separately, whereas with HD wallets all pairs "address + private key" are generated with a single list of words known as **seed**.

I'm interested in HD wallets but I know almost nothing about them and all the terminology I've found on the internet is very confusing to me. I've found terms like **BIP39 Mnemonic**, **BIP39 Passphrase**, **BIP39 Seed**, **BIP32 Root Key**, **Master Private Key**, **Derivation Path**, **BIP44**, **m/44'/0'/0'/0/0**, and so on (see [iancoleman.io/bip39](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/), for example). I'd like to be able to organize this into something that makes sense and I can understand.

Once I've created an HD wallet and I have a list of pairs "address + private key", how can I access it and spend funds from a specific private key from the list? Which software shoud I use and what is the easiest way to do it without compromising security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any BIP39 compatible software to enter a mnemonic (12-24 words) and turn it into a seed. Seed is just a number between 1 and 2^256. You can then use this seed to create a Master Private Key. This key then serves as the root of a chain used to create other private keys based on a derivation path.

The whole process is deterministic so same mnemonic and same path will always lead to the same key. Once you have a normal private key you can import it to any bitcoin client and access the funds as usual.

Comment: So, it is NOT mandatory to access the whole HD wallet in order to spend funds from a specific private key inside that wallet, right? I mean, if I have only one of the wallet's private keys, I can spend the funds by using a wallet created at [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/) for example?

Comment: @UserX That's right. Check out the Derived addresses table in the bottom of your link. It lists one normal private key for each derivation path.